# I am not getting the beforeunload event from window object

Tags: javascript, frontend, chat, call, onbeforeunload

I have two functions to call and join an existing call. Here is the functions.

```
  const call = ({ mode }) => {
    callWindows[id] = window.open(`/call/${mode}/${id}`, '_blank', 'width=auto, height=auto');
    callWindows[id].addEventListener('beforeunload', () => delete callWindows[id]);
    socket.emit('call', { chatId: id, mode });
  };

  const join = (chatId, data) => {
    if (callWindows[chatId]) return callWindows[chatId].focus();
    callWindows[chatId] = window.open(`/call/${data.mode}/${chatId}`, '_blank', 'width=auto, height=auto');
    return callWindows[chatId].addEventListener('beforeunload', () => delete callWindows[id]);
  };
```

In both functions the `beforeunload` event is not firing.

How can I fix it to get the event?

Comment: How do you know that it's not fired?

Comment: @Konrad I have tried console.log in the callbacks.

Comment: Weird that works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/d459v1Lm/ Could you try removing stuff that are being done in the popup and check if / when the problem resolves?

Comment: And is the popup also connected to the same socket instance? Maybe you could have the server notify the main page when it sees the child has been disconnected.